# In what circumstance might I need to output pixels in non-32-bit format?

Tags: graphics, color, cross-platform, pixel

Among practically existing devices people play games with - PC, mobile, PlayStation, XBox, Nintendo etc. - is there any possibility that a pixel on the screen is not 32-bit, and do I have to consider this for portability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the most notable area where more exotic pixel colour formats might come up is when using a high dynamic range (HDR) display, with a platform that supports it.

PC, Xbox One S/X / Series S/X, and PS4 / PS5 all support HDR output.

For example, [the HDR10 spec uses 10 bits per colour channel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDR10), instead of the usual 8 used for SDR output.

In some situations you might output your frame in ARGBHalf format (16 bits per colour channel, 64 bits per pixel). [This is often the default HDR output format in Unity, for example](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTextureFormat.DefaultHDR.html).